# Why am I getting a white screen without a slash at the end of the address?

Tags: theme-development, urls

I am currently building a custom Wordpress theme for my rugby team. I just noticed something and I can't work out whether this has been happening for a while and I have only just noticed it or it is a new thing.

It would appear that any page address without a slash at the end of the address renders a white screen of death.

For example

```
(url)/fixtures/
```

works fine but

```
(url)/fixtures
```

Gives me a WSOD

Comment: Have you tried removing the trailing slash in your permalink structure from Settings->Permalinks and then save the changes? http://d.pr/i/X2sR

Comment: Typical behavior is a redirect from slash-less to slashed. Do you have this trouble with a buncled theme like Twenty Fourteen and with plugins disabled?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my own problem by debugging all the different functions.php includes.

One of the files had some whitespace at the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, turns out i had  ?> at the end of functions.php that was NOT needed. Deleted it and all is fixed.

Comment: who down voted this? lol